# Extract the object names from different nesting levels in JSON

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to get the solution from my former question to running [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830955/get-the-elements-from-nested-json-with-python-using-json-lib), but unfortunately without success. I'm trying right now to change the code to deliver me in result not the Ids, but the "name" values itself. [JSON](http://pastebin.com/MDPv0PND) this is my json, I want to extract the SUB, SUBSUB and NAME and when using a quasi for-chain, I cound not get back in hierarchy to get the SUBSUB2... Could anyone please put me somehow on the right track?

The solution code from the former question:

```
def locateByName(e,name):
    if e.get('name',None) == name:
        return e

    for child in e.get('children',[]):
        result = locateByName(child,name)
        if result is not None:
            return result

    return None
```

What I exactly want to achieve is simple list as SUB1, SUBSUB1, NAME1, NAME2, SUBSUB2, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your JSON,

```
def trav(node, acc = []):
    acc += [node['name']]
    if 'children' in node:
        for child in node['children']:
            trav(child, acc)

acc = []
trav(x, acc)
print acc
```

Output:

```
['MAIN', 'SUB1', 'SUBSUB1', 'NAME1', 'NAME2', 'SUBSUB2', 'SUBSUB3']
```

Another, more compact solution:

```
from itertools import chain         

def trav(node):
    if 'children' in node:
        return [node['name']] + list(chain.from_iterable([trav(child) for child in node['children']]))
    else:
        return [node['name']]

print trav(x)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is perfect. And this is what is on Stackoverflow the best - the possibility to learn, I didn't knew the itertools lib. :)